# Fetching Arbitrarily Large Number of Objects in Parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform

In my Parse database, I have a "Connection" class which joins two users. In one of my methods I am trying to fetch all users an individual is connected to. However, I am stuck between two different options, neither of which seems very efficient.

My first reaction was to continuously query the db until all the objects are returned (e.g. "query first 1000, query second 1000, ..."). In most cases this would be ideal since the majority of users will have less than 1000 connections (probably more like 2-300 or so). However, if some user has an insane number of connections this won't really work too well - particularly since Parse has burst limits.

The other option seems to be to use the Query.each method, to simply iterate over all records that match the query. I believe this will work regardless of the number of elements, so that is good. However, it sounds like this is relatively slow for large sizes and will probably time out.

So, what would be the best way to do this with the limitations of Parse? I want it to be fast in the common case of a relatively low number of objects, yet it should certainly not break for edge cases. Certainly one option would be to just not do this type of query, but it is very helpful to have all the connections on client side. Thanks!

Comment: Can you query the number of connections first? Then you would know exactly how many to expect.

Comment: I could, yes. But Parse has a maximum limit of 1000 per query. So even if I know the size is 10k, I'd still have to do 10 queries.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking. This is a good question I am not sure why someone down voted it, but I voted up because I am interested to see what other people can come up with.

Comment: So paging through the connections is not an option. I am trying to understand why you would need all 10k to be on client.

Comment: I could probably find a work-around. It is just helpful to have a list of them in memory, since usually the users do not have many connections so it makes everything quicker/simpler. Sounds like it may be hard to rely on this fact though.

Comment: Could you just limit the connections you show the user? Show them at most 1000 that way you never have to worry about multiple queries. If they need to find a specific connection then have a search bar that you can use to limit your query?

Comment: Yeah this is probably along the lines of what I will do. Fortunately this isn't a super comment case so not the end of the world if I have to occasionally load additional data. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Great question, and one that I have found a good solution to for my own work. The fastest, most efficient workaround is to query the object count, and if it's more than 1000 run multiple queries on the same table, with query's skip property incremented by 1000 each time:

Get the total number of records via `[query countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock]`, and use it to set a 'skip' variable. Run a new query for each 1000 records, updating your skip property accordingly
process records as normal when each query returns.

You also need a helper method to determine when all the queries are complete and you are ready to process the complete data set locally.

Something like this:

```
//Define these as class-wide variables in your @interface - don't forget to @synthesize them too!
int queriesToComplete;
int completedQueries;
NSMutableArray *completeDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//Put in your query load function
PFQuery *recordsCountQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"YourClassName"];
[recordsCountQuery countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int number, NSError *error) {
    //Determine how many queries to run
    queriesToComplete = (int)ceil(number/1000) + 1;
    //Set the number of completed queries to zero
    completedQueries = 0;
    //Run a chain of queries - be sure to run them in the background to prevent UI lockup
    for (int i = 0; i < queriesToComplete; i++) {
        PFQuery *chainQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"YourClassName"];
        //Add your other 'whereKey: equalTo:' type qualifiers here
        chainQuery.limit = 1000;
        chainQuery.skip = (i*1000);
        [chainQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            //NSLog(@"query done");
            [completeDataArray addObjectsFromArray:[objects copy]];
            completedQueries ++;
            [self pullCompletionCheck];
        }];
    }
}];

- (void)pullCompletionCheck{
    if (self.queriesToComplete == self.completedQueries) {
        //All queries completed.  
        //All data is now in the completeDataArray

    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I think this is generally the most logical way to do it. It sucks for edge cases with a ton of objects since it would require a ton of queries (at some point enough to hit your burst limit I would imagine), but this is good for simple cases for sure. Thanks!